# How can I solve the problem TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'returnValue') in my unit test?

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine, return-value

I have a method `loadProducts` in one of the components and wrote a test to check it. As a result, it returns me a mistake:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'returnValue').

I tried different ways but couldn't solve the problem. Help me, where can we use returnValue method and when we can't use it?

This is my method:

```js
    loadProducts(): void {
    this.category = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('category') as string;
    this.productService.getAllByCategory(this.category).subscribe(data => {
      this.userProducts = data;
    })
    }
```

And this is my whole file with unit test for this function:

```js
    import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

    import { ProductsComponent } from './products.component';
    import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
    import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
    import { IProductResponse } from 'src/app/shared/interfaces/IProduct';
    import { ProductService } from 'src/app/shared/services/products/product.service';
    import { of } from 'rxjs';

    describe('ProductsComponent', () => {
    let mockProductService:any;
    let component: ProductsComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<ProductsComponent>;
    let PRODUCT: IProductResponse;
    let PRODUCTS: IProductResponse[];

    beforeEach(async () => {
    mockProductService = jasmine.createSpyObj({'getAllByCategory':of(PRODUCTS)});
    PRODUCT = {
      category: {
        id: 1,
        name: 'pizza',
        path: 'string',
        imagePath: 'string',
      },
      id: 1,
      name: 'string',
      path: 'string',
      ingredients: 'string',
      weight: 'string',
      price: 1,
      imagePath: 'string',
      count: 1,
    };
    PRODUCTS =[{
      category: {
        id: 1,
        name: 'pizza',
        path: 'string',
        imagePath: 'string',
      },
      id: 1,
      name: 'string',
      path: 'string',
      ingredients: 'string',
      weight: 'string',
      price: 1,
      imagePath: 'string',
      count: 1,
    },
    {
      category: {
        id: 1,
        name: 'pizza',
        path: 'string',
        imagePath: 'string',
      },
      id: 2,
      name: 'string',
      path: 'string',
      ingredients: 'string',
      weight: 'string',
      price: 1,
      imagePath: 'string',
      count: 1,
    }];
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [ProductsComponent],
      providers:[
        {provide:ProductService, useValue:mockProductService}
      ]
    })
      .compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ProductsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();

    });

    it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('should test loadProducts()', ()=>{
    let category = 'pizza';
    mockProductService.getAllByCategory(category).and.returnValue(of(PRODUCTS))
    expect(component.userProducts).toEqual(PRODUCTS);

  });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

remove this:

> mockProductService =
> jasmine.createSpyObj({'getAllByCategory':of(PRODUCTS)});

inject your `ProductService` in your beforeEach method.

```
service = TestBed.inject(ProductService);
```

spy on the method in your service, then call the loadProducts method that calls the getAllByCategory function.

```
spyOn(service, 'getAllByCategory').and.returnValue(of(PRODUCT));
component.loadProducts();
expect(component.userProducts).toEqual(PRODUCTS);
```

Comment: Okay, thank you! It works. But I read that it's better to use mocks of services. Why it didn't work out with jasmine.createSpyObj and returnValue. I can't find any info

Comment: yours didn't work because the syntax is wrong. @AliF50 has the correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do it like this:

```
// The first argument is optional and it is for debugging purposes.
// The 2nd argument is an array of public methods you would like to mock.
mockProductService = jasmine.createSpyObj('ProductService', ['getAllByCategory']);

// Then mockProductService.getAllByCategory should be defined.
mockProductService.getAllByCategory(category).and.returnValue(of(PRODUCTS))
```